# how to Test Idle(is not currently active) user using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to assert on popup that only show up if the user still idle for amount of time without doing any action using cypress

```js
cy.wait(100*1000)
cy.get('popupTitle').should('be.visible')
```

The popup is not showing up ( it shows up if i do it manually)

Comment: What is the idle time? I presume it's greater than 100 seconds, since you wait that long.

Comment: Please note, you don't have to wait the whole period, take a look at [cy.clock()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock#Examples) - but it won't solve your problem if you waited longer than the idle time.

Comment: If this is implemented in Python please post a sample of the code so I can see what is behind the idle mechanism.

Comment: I have to wait 90 sec but cy.wait() wait for a number of milliseconds so actually, this is a 100 sec

Answer (score 3):

Please try using the [cy.clock()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock#Access-the-clock-object-to-synchronously-move-time) command to control the time within the app.

```js
cy.clock().then((clock) => {
  clock.tick(100_000)
})
cy.get('popupTitle').should('be.visible')
```

You must leave the app in the background, or test with `cypress run --headless` as the Cypress runner is live.